# Excel: How to get the cell address of a hlookup reference?

Tags: excel, reference, cell, lookup

I have a hlookup formula and the result is a number from another worksheet. In the cell next to this result I would like to have the cell address (from the other worksheet) that the hlookup references.

I've played around with the CELL formula but I can't combine it with an index/match because there are duplicate numbers in the reference worksheet

Answer (score 0):

Use `Address to return the address of a cell reference

If you are using this to get the value

```
=HLOOKUP("LookupValue", LookupRange, n, 0)
```

, use this to get the address

```
=ADDRESS(Row(LookupRange) + n - 1, MATCH("LookupValue",LookupRangeRow1,0))
```